# Different models in one view

Tags: python, django

Hi I am very new in django. I wonder if I could user different models in one view.
So I looked this page https://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/editing-multiple-objects-in-django-with-newforms/
It was so useful but I couldn't see output on browser page. Where did I made mistake?

## my views

```
from .models import Contact, MyUser
from .forms import ContactForm, UserRegisterForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def total_register(request):
uform = UserRegisterForm()
cform = ContactForm()
if request.method == "POST":
    uform = UserRegisterForm(request.POST or None, instance=MyUser())
    cform = [ContactForm(request.POST or None, prefix=str(x), instance=Contact()) for x in range(0,19)]
    if uform.is_valid() and all([cf.is_valid() for cf in cform]):
        new_MyUser = uform.save()
        for cf in cform:
            new_contact = cf.save(commit=False)
            new_contact.MyUser = new_MyUser
            new_contact.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
                pform = UserRegisterForm(instance=MyUser())
                cform = [ContactForm(prefix=str(x), instance=Contact()) for x in range(0,19)]
return render_to_response('total_register.html', {'UserRegisterForm': uform, 'ContactForm': cform})
```

## my forms

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
username = forms.CharField(label = 'isminizi giriniz')
lastname = forms.CharField(label = 'soyisminizi giriniz')    
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)


class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        'username',
        'lastname',
    ]
def signup(self, request, user):
    user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
    user.lastname = self.cleaned_data['lastname']


    user.save()




class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Contact
    fields = ['username','soyad','cinsiyet','unvan','kurum',"bolum","gorev", "uzmanlik","adres","posta_kodu","sehir","ulke","is_tel","ev_tel","fax_no","cep_tel","email"]
```

## my urls

```
    url(r'^kayit/', bildirge.views.total_register, name = 'kayit'),
```

## my html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}
<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<hr/>

<form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }}
<button type='submit'>gonder</button>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: welcome to SO! you may want to use Django's [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: what is error you get?

Comment: When I go the url of this view I see nothing but send button. It should show me forms isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the variable `form` in your template, but you are passing `UserRegisterForm` and `ContactForm` as template context.

Try something like:

```
<form...>

{{ UserRegisterForm }}
{% for form in ContactForm %}
{{ form }}
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

Two hints:

- check out [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/) for handling multiple forms of the same type
- please make sure your code is correctly indented, especially with Python

Comment: Thanks for your precious time. It worked but not efficiently, there are thousands of forms in my page. Forms start again and again... Is it because of the code I wrote in Python or your Html ?

Answer (score 0):

You've sent two variables to your template, with the keys `UserRegisterForm` and `ContactForm`. You have to use those names in your template, not just `form`.